# remotely run a script sitting in a windows server from a unix box or from another desktop (Say windowS)

Tags: scripting, shell, batch-file, remote-access

I have to run a batch job which sits in the windows server from my unix box.
Or from my local machine.
The win server has a userName/Pwd .
How do i programmatically connect to the windows machine and run the batch?
(The batch will change some file permissions in that machine)

Please let me know if there is a better way of handling this situation

Answer (score 0):

A lot of this depends on how you authenticate on the windows machine, the network relation you have to it from your local and unix machine and what level of permission you will need to run the task ons the remote batch file.

I can say that in Windows, you could start by possibly creating a script that stores the username and password needed to connect to the remote machine in a variable, and in that script have it connect to the machine over a network and run the batch as that user.

How woudl you connect to the remote windows server? is it on a LAN or VPN type environment, do you connect with ssh or do you normally map it over the network?>